# How to handle multiple consoles in single application?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, console-application

I've done my research but for now I have no idea how to handle this. I'm doing a project with selenium (important thing as selenium using console to handle connection with browser) and I need to use third party - console application (it is .exe file). I can not use console thought, because it is already taken from selenium. I'm using c#.

As far as I know, there is impossible to handle 2 consoles in 1 application. Final product would be winforms application. Do you have any ideas how to approach this?

System.Diagnostics.Process only opens program but not communicating with this - and I know I'm doing right implementation.

Comment: You're not very clear. Selenium doesn't "use" the console, C# does. So, if you need to run some C# code that sends info to the console output window at the same time as selenium, that works. If you need to run two seperate console apps, one for selenium, one for something else, just run two different apps.

Comment: To clarify: I want use .exe program which involves communicate throught console. It doesn't work when I'm using selenium at same time. When I'm using only .exe program (without selenium) then it's working perfectly. I'm assuming it's because I can not have 2 consoles at same time. Similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671163/can-you-have-multiple-net-consoles-as-in-console-writeline but I have to use consoles (only way to communicate with this .exe program),

Comment: See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902672/multiple-consoles-at-once, which links to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13368/Multiple-consoles-for-a-single-application